# Sequelize Nested Association with Two Tables

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have a scenario where I am trying to query a parent table (document) with two associated tables (reference & user) that do not have a relationship to each other, but do have a relationship with the parent table. In SQL, this query would look like such and correctly outputs the data I am looking for:

```sql
select *
from `document`
left join `user`
on `document`.`user_id` = `user`.`user_id`
left join `reference`
on `document`.`reference_id` = `reference`.`reference_id`
where `user`.`organization_id` = 1;
```

However, associations that are nested have to relate in hierarchical order in order for the query to work. Since the nested associations are not related to each other I get an association error. How can I avoid this error? Would `required: false` have any influence on this?

```js
models.Document.findAll({
  order: 'documentDate DESC',
  include: [{
    model: models.User,
    where: { organizationId: req.user.organizationId },
    include: [{
      model: models.Reference,
    }]
  }],
})
```

**Error**:

> Unhandled rejection Error: reference is not associated to user!

**Associations**:

**`Document`**:

```js
associate: function(db) {
  Document.belongsTo(db.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'}),
    Document.belongsTo(db.Reference, { foreignKey: 'reference_id'});;
}
```

**`Reference`**:

```js
associate: function(db){
  Reference.hasMany(db.Document, { foreignKey: 'reference_id' });
}
```

Should I just chain queries instead?

Comment: It looks like you specify `underscored: true` but are using cameCase names: `organization_id` vs `organizationId` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to replicate your query (as closely as possibly) use the following query. Keep in mind that the `where` on the User `include` will only serve to remove matches on `Document.user_id` where the `User.organization_id` does not match, but the `Document` will still be returned. If you want to omit Documents where the `User.organization_id` does not match use `required: true`.

`User <- Document -> Reference`

```js
models.Document.findAll({
  // this is an array of includes, don't nest them
  include: [{
    model: models.User,
    where: { organization_id: req.user.organization_id }, // <-- underscored HERE
    required: true, // <-- JOIN to only return Documents where there is a matching User
  },
  {
    model: models.Reference,
    required: false, // <-- LEFT JOIN, return rows even if there is no match
  }],
  order: [['document_date', 'DESC']], // <-- underscored HERE, plus use correct format
});
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! I have been trying to figure out how to join multiple tables that are associated to a parent table, but not together and this solved the issue. How did you know to nest both within the include array rather than nest another include within the first? I don't believe I have ever found this in documentation or within any community answers.

Comment: It depends on your data model. Like I mentioned before (and why my first answer was incorrect) when you nest them you change the type of relationship to `Document->User->Reference`, when really you wanted `Document->User` + `Document->Reference`.

Comment: You don't really need `required: true` when you are using the `where` clause.

Comment: @keshavAggarwal that's correct, `required: true` is the default value, I just included it to make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

The error is indicating that the `User` model is not associated to the `Reference` model, but there are only definitions for the `Document` and `Reference` models in your description. You are joining these tables in your query with the `include` option, so you have to make sure they are associated. You don't technically need the `foreignKey` here either, you are specifying the default values.

**Add `Reference->User` association**

```js
associate: function(db) {
  // belongsTo()? maybe another relationship depending on your data model
  Reference.belongsTo(db.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'});

  Reference.hasMany(db.Document, { foreignKey: 'reference_id' });
}
```

It also looks like you probably set `underscored: true` in your model definitions, so your query should reflect this. Additionally if you want to perform a `LEFT JOIN` you need to specify `required: false` on the `include`, otherwise it is a regular `JOIN` and you will only get back rows with matches in the `include`d model. You are also using the wrong `order` format, it should be an array of values, and to sort by `model.document_date DESC` you should use `order: [['document_date', 'DESC']]`.

**Proper query arguments**

```js
models.Document.findAll({
  order: [['document_date', 'DESC']], // <-- underscored HERE, plus use correct format
  include: [{
    model: models.User,
    where: { organization_id: req.user.organization_id }, // <-- underscored HERE
    required: false, // <-- LEFT JOIN
    include: [{
      model: models.Reference,
      required: false, // <-- LEFT JOIN
    }]
  }],
});
```

If you are still having trouble, try enabling logging by setting `logging: console.log` in your Sequelize connection, that will show you all the queries it is running in your console.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed comment and noticed that I never added detail about the User model. The reason why I left it out outside of the brief reference is because there is no association on that model that is related to the two other tables mentioned (Document and Reference). My question is doesn't associating tables without a foreign key defeat the purpose of what an association should be? A relationship between tables with an FK? Would a raw query be the a better route since Reference isn't directly related to User?

Comment: Your query reflects that the association is `Document->User->Reference`.

Comment: Do you mean to query `Document->User` and `Document->Reference`?

Comment: `Document -> User` and `Document -> Reference` is the correct way to put together the relationships. Document is linked to both tables, but they aren't linked to each other. I believe this also mimics the double left join in the SQL query in the question.

Comment: I posted a different answer based on your original query and that information. Not knowing your requirements my guess is that you need to make the user include required since you probably want to exclude documents for users in the wrong organization...?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem might be the associations, trying to link back to your primary key on Documents instead of the columns 'user_id' and 'reference_id'. You didn't post the table attributes so I might have understood this wrong.

Association on documents are ok.

## Documents

```
associate: function(db) {
  Document.belongsTo(db.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'}),  //key in documents
  Document.belongsTo(db.Reference, { foreignKey: 'reference_id'}); //key in documents
}
```

## User

```
associate: function(db) {
  User.belongsTo(db.Document, {
    foreignKey: 'id',    //Key in User
    targetKey: 'user_id' //Key in Documents
  }),
}
```

## Reference

```
associate: function(db) {
  Reference.belongsTo(db.Document, {
      foreignKey: 'id',         //Key in reference
      targetKey: 'reference_id' //Key in Documents
  }),
}
```

## Also

For debbuging consider using logging so you can see the queries.

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
    logging: console.log
    logging: function (str) {
        // do your own logging
    }
});
```